# Can't use ObservableCollection in a Grid?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I am currently working with a Xamarin app for reading RFID temperature tags and updating their values in real time. The current setup uses two Horizontal StackLayouts, one with a ListView showing a list of tags and their values, and the other with a Grid of Images of the human body that I wish to display the values on as well (in specific places).

In the ListView side, I can successfully call an object called TagInfoList, which is an ObservableCollection in the Class I call from the BasePage initialization. However, on the Grid side, I've tried multiple methods of using the TagInfoList, but it does not work. I've tried BindableLayouts, DataTemplates + ViewCells, and none allow me to get TagInfoList usable within my second StackLayout.

Here is the XAML code for the two horizontal StackLayouts:

````
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
          <ListView x:Name="liewViewTagData" ItemsSource="{Binding TagInfoList}" SelectedItem="{Binding objItemSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.Header>
              <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#cccccc">
                <Grid>
                  <!-- Grid + Label code irrelevant to my issue-->
                </Grid>
              </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Grid>
                      <!-- Grid + Label code irrelevant to my issue-->
                    </Grid>
                  </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </StackLayout> <!-- RFID Tag Section -->

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"> <!-- Body Model Section -->
          <!-- HERE: WHAT TO PUT FOR TagInfoList TO BE USABLE? -->
          <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="400" ColumnSpacing="0">
             <!-- Grid + Label + Images I want to use TagInfoList information in -->
          </Grid>
          <!-- HERE: WHAT TO PUT FOR TagInfoList TO BE USABLE? -->
        </StackLayout> <!-- Body Model Section -->
      </StackLayout>```
````

I've deleted the bulk of inside Grids since it's not relevant. TagInfoList is an ObservableCollection of a class which contains all the data I need (strings and ints). How do I utilize TagInfoList within the second StackLayout? If I do it the same method as the first StackLayout, I get an error that I've called TagInfoList twice (through the 'liewViewTagData' item). Here is that code in the .xaml.cs file:

```
liewViewTagData.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;     // Don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // De-select the row
            };
```

My sole goal is to use the TagInfoList ObservableCollection within both StackLayouts, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: this has nothing to do with StackLayout.  Your first usage is a StackLayout bound to an ObservableCollection.  Your second one is a Grid, which isn't really bindable. There is a lengthy explanation on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).  You need to use a ListView or CollectionView, or a layout that is more easily bindable.

Comment: The problem *isn't* "trying to use it in multiple StackLayouts". You can test this by commenting out the FIRST usage, and trying to get the second usage to work. The real problem is that it is *meaningless* to use a collection with a Grid. I've edited question title to indicate this. Grid needs to be told rows and columns. SOLUTION: [CollectionView Layout Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout) - see section on "Grid-like" layout.

Comment: I meant "Your first usage is a **ListView** bound to an .."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I do it the same method as the first StackLayout, I get an error
> that I've called TagInfoList twice (through the 'liewViewTagData'
> item).

You can do it in the same way as the first `StackLayout`.And you can change property `x:Name` of the two listviews  to different `Name`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
     <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <ListView  x:Name="liewViewTagData" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{ Binding TagInfoList}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                                <!--other code-->

                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <ListView  x:Name="liewView2" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{ Binding TagInfoList}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                                <!--other code-->
                                
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Note:

If you run out of horizontal space, I suggest you add a `ScrollView` to the outer layer.